# Can someone please explain this circuit especially the role of "KEY 1"?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, batteries, protection

I am  currently studying different power management circuits and I came across this one ,  can anyone explain to me the role of "KEY 1" ? [image]

for reference , P+ and P- re coming from a USB charging port ( used to harge batteries) :
[image]

Comment: It's probably explained in the HY2120 datasheet.

Comment: Chinglish quote from the datasheet: "Notice: Discharging may not be enacted when the battery is first time connected. To regain normal status, CS and VSS PIN must be shorted or the charger must be connected"

Comment: It's some kind of power on reset to make the chinese circuit inside work. Only it's manual since once started the chip is not supposed to be ever powered down (it lives with the battery pack, usually). Probably that circuit has an operating scenario where it is disconnected